# Grails 3 interceptors intercepts static resources(resolves 'js' and 'css' file path as controller, action) and executes before() call on it

Tags: grails, interceptor, grails3

I am using grails 3.2.7. 
Can anyone please tell me how to prevent Interceptor to intercept static resources?

it's currently intercepting

```
<script src="/appName/js/apps/file.js"></script>
```

as

```
controllerName == js, actionName == apps, params == [controller:js, action:apps, id:file.js]
```

can anyone help me with a way to prevent such interception. I want my Interceptor should only work for controller, actions. Not for static resources.

Comment: That sounds like a bug.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and link to a sample app which demonstrates the problem, we can get it straightened out.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown

Seems like this was intentionally done with https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9724

But I have certain code in my interceptor that should only work when it hit any controller, action.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown: I have created the question at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10779
Please check.Thanks!

Comment: I think the change was intentional.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown But is there a way to prevent such interception to static resource ?

Comment: "But is there a way to prevent such interception to static resource ?" - Yes.  One way to do that is to only match requests to certain controllers.

Comment: We are discussing adding something like `matchAllControllers()` in addition to `matchAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but what works is excluding uris that hold the static content e.g. like so in the constructor of an interceptor

```
RobotsInterceptor() {
    matchAll().except(uri: '/js/**')
            .except(uri: '/css/**')
            .except(uri: '/icons/**')
            .except(uri: '/images/**')
            .except(uri: '/fonts/**')
            .except(uri: '/static/**')
            .except(uri: '/asset-manifest.json')
            .except(uri: '/fav.ico')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling that library like this:

```
<g:javascript src="/appName/js/apps/file.js"/>
```